# Is there a way to reverse a function in python?

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a program that takes a string and turns it into what looks like a random sequence of characters but can be turned back into the original string later.

I have a function that does this, and I was just wondering if there is any way to undo a function without having to write another function that undoes it like that.

Something like function(parameters).undo.

Here is my code:

```
def hash(p):
    string = ""
    num = 0
    str2 = 0

    for i in range(12):
        p += chr(random.randint(42, 126))

    for i in p:
        num = math.ceil((ord(i) + 5) / 2)

        if num < 42:
            str2 = num
        if len(str(str2)) == 1:
            str2 = str("0" + str(str2))

        string += str(chr(num + 42))

        if (ord(i) + 5) % 2 == 1:
            string += "n"
        else:
            string += "m"

        string += str(chr(int(str2) + 42))

    strlist = [i for a,i in enumerate(string)]
    random.shuffle(strlist, lambda: .5)

    return strlist
```

I searched the problem and got nothing but list.reverse()

Comment: No. This would be very complicated (and often impossible) to do for any non-trivial function.

Comment: Even in terms of pure functions — mapping input to output — not all functions are invertible. The first requirement is that the each input maps to a unique output. Consider the function `add(a, b)` so `add(4, 5)` returns `9`. But given `9` you can't go back to unambiguously because `add(8, 1)` or `add(1009, -1000)` also map to 9. It's not invertible.

Comment: To unhash the sequence, you'd need to work backward through your algorithm. It's not as simple as just applying an undo method. You need a corresponding function to reverse it.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible in Python (or most/any other languages). For any function that does slightly complicated branching or even common math operations, it is completely impossible to undo. One very simple example:

```
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b

foo.undo(6)  # made-up example syntax
```

What should this return? `0` and `6`, or maybe `-13` and `19`? A reversible function needs to have an unambiguous mapping from both input to output **and** output to input. Anything in the function that would cause two different inputs to create the same output will break this mapping.

Especially in your example, you are utilizing randomness. How could the program even know what to undo if it is randomized? The mapping isn't even consistent for input to output, much less the other way around.

If you want to do something like this, you could use simple substitutions only (such as [rot13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)), which provides a direct mapping between characters. You could also keep track of previous values in a `dict` with the function results being the keys, which would work because it is creating the mapping as it goes. This obviously would not work on its own across multiple runs of the program though, as it would not preserve the mapping.

Whichever method you choose, you will definitely need to write your own undo function.

Comment: This is a great example that gets right to the root of the problem with just a super simple function. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Many answers have pointed out how what you're describing (reversing the actions of a generic function) is mathematically impossible. I'll show you here a way you could accomplish this under some very specific circumstances, though I will hasten to point out that they are correct -- this will not work in the general case.

However, if you're frequently round-tripping these results, it might be helpful to memoize the results of your `hash` function and do a reverse lookup.

```py
# This code assumes that the memo dictionary need not be bounded in size.
# A real implementation will likely include a method to cull old results
# once the memo reaches a certain size. See `functools.lru_cache` for a
# specific example of this made for speeding up repeated function calls.

_memo_dict = dict()

def hash(p):
    # produces strlist as above, then...

    _key = tuple(strlist)
    _memo_dict[_key] = p

def unhash(hashed_p: list[int]) -> str:
    cache_hit = _memo_dict.get(tuple(hashed_p))
    if cache_hit is not None:
        # we've previously hashed a string to get this
        # value so we can skip the calculations to reverse
        # the process and just hand back the result
        return cache_hit

    # otherwise, you should have some way to reverse it
    # manually here.
```

Comment: OP should be aware that their current hash function won't be completely undoable with this method because of the randomness and other mapping-breaking operations. Only hashes previously generated within the same program run will be reversible. (That is, the "reverse it manually here" section couldn't be written)

Comment: @LukeB I haven't read their function comprehensively, but I believe they actually strip all randomness out of `hash`. Their shuffle function has a set seed, and while they generate a bunch of random integers and `chr` them, it appears they then filter them all out just below where they keep only those characters whose `ord` is below 42.

Comment: Ah actually, on closer inspection, they can definitely end up with those random integers undisturbed in the output hash. I retract my previous comment!